# How do I read the entire content of a given file into a string?

Tags: ocaml

My given file /path/file.txt contains for example the following:

> Hello World!
>  Try to read me.

How can I read the **entire** content into **one single** string inside my code?
For this specific example, the string should look like this:

```
"Hello World!\nTry to read me."
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you don't want to use Core, the following works with functions from the built-in Stdlib module (formerly called Pervasives):

```
let read_whole_file filename =
    (* open_in_bin works correctly on Unix and Windows *)
    let ch = open_in_bin filename in
    let s = really_input_string ch (in_channel_length ch) in
    close_in ch;
    s
```

Comment: On Windows with DOS (CRLF) line endings, `really_input_string` will likely raise `End_of_file` as `in_channel_length` doesn't do character conversions but `open_in` does, and the number of characters expected will be more than the number of characters read after conversion. One possible solution is to use `open_in_bin`.

Comment: Yes, absolutely.

Answer (score 8):

For the solution below to work, you need to use `Core` library by Jane Street by writing `open Core` on any line above the place where you use any of the code below.

`In_channel.read_all "./input.txt"` returns you the content of `input.txt` in the current folder in a single string.

Also useful:

- `In_channel.read_lines "./input.txt"` returns a list of lines in the file
- `In_channel.fold_lines` allows to "fold over" all lines in the file.